# How to remove gap between dropdown ul inside ul with html and css

Tags: html, css

I don't know what's wrong with my code, I followed a tutorial on youtube to create a navbar with html and css. But, my design shows a gap between dropdown and the parent ul

I've looking for the answer in StackOverflow,  trying the answer I found in StackOverflow, but it doesn't work either.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

header {
 background-color: #217e6a;
 height: 66px;
 color: white;
}
header * {
 color: white;
}

header .logo {
 padding-left: 2em;
 padding-right: 2em;
 float: left;
 height: inherit;
 background-color: #0f5042;
}

header .logo-text {
 margin: 5px;
}

header ul {
 float: right;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}

header ul li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid red;
 vertical-align: top;
}

header ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 66px;
 right: 0px;
 width: 200px;
 display: none;
 background-color: #217e6a;
 border: 1px solid black;
 vertical-align: top;
}

header ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

header ul li ul li {
 width: 100%;
}

headerulli ul li:hover {
 background-color: #0f5042;
}

header ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 21px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-decoration: none;
}

header ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #0f5042;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/admin.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="logo-text">
                <h1>COVID-19 BJN</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="header_profile">Profile</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sign Out</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

That's my code. Please help me how to fix that. Thanks

Comment: Change top:66px to 65px

Comment: @j08691 But it'll make the hover overlay the header

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN You still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Manjuboyz yes I am

Comment: so what it should do when you hover on the menu? it should align right at the bottom of header ends?

Comment: @Manjuboyz there is a gap between profile nav and the dropdown, i want the profile nav  has the same height as the header and no gap on the dropdown

Comment: height or width? if it is height I don't see any differences in height and yeah there is a gap between header and dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `a` tag should have the height that is why you don't see full height.

> NOTE: If you use a border then you have to decrease a pixel property to height since the border will fill that content, so you have to toggle between that requirement and should decide what is needed.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  background-color: #217e6a;
  height: 65px;
  color: red;
}

header * {
  color: white;
}

header .logo {
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  float: left;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #0f5042;
}

header .logo-text {
  margin: 5px;
}

header ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 0px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

header ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #217e6a;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}

header ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

header ul li ul li {
  width: 100%;
}

headerulli ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0f5042;
}

header ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 21px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 65px;
}

header ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0f5042;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css" rel="stylesheet">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/admin.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="logo-text">
        <h1>COVID-19 BJN</h1>
      </div>

    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="header_profile">Profile</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sign Out</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN glad it worked! would you mind voting the answer if you think worth voting?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here

```
header ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #217e6a;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

You have the absolute positioning too low down, just change the `top` and make it slightly higher and the gap will be gone.